# Is it safe to truncate the key_value_expire table?

Tags: 8, database

I am seeing over 8 GB in the database for the *key_value_expire* table.

Is it safe to manually truncate that table?
This appears to be caused by a bug in the Honeypot Module, which I am unable to uninstall without throwing an error.

Comment: It should be safe, but if you've identified a problematic module it would be arguably safer to just delete the related records rather than the whole lot. You can filter on the `collection` field for that

Comment: check this answer to understand the purpose of **key_value_expire** table https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/221985/what-is-the-purpose-of-key-value-expire-table#answer-221994

Comment: To @Clive's point, why not delete just the problematic values with the update hook supplied in a patch for the related honeypot bug? [Write update hook to clean up old honeypot_time_restriction values](https://www.drupal.org/project/honeypot/issues/2997609)